# How to bind to properties in DataTemplate when using the template elsewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, templates, binding

I have a DataGrid which has cells with a label and a ProgressBar. I bind variables from a struct to the label Content and the ProgresBar Value property, like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <ProgressBar Value="{Binding BindPerc}" Maximum="1"/>
      <Label Content="{Binding Bind}"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Now I have many columns and multiply DataGrids which all use the same CellTemplate the only difference being the bindings. Right now most of my XAML is redundant code, therefore it makes sense to implement this template in the Window.Ressources and then use the CellTemplate.

This is my code for the column and cell templates

Column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn
  Header="BindName"
  SortMemberPath="Bind"
  CellTemplate="ProgressCell"/>
```

Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProgressCell">
  <Grid>
    <ProgressBar x:Name="CellProgressBar" Maximum="1"/>
    <Label x:Name="CellLabel"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**How do I set the bindings for the CellLabel.Content and the CellProgressBar.Value properties in the DataGridTemplateColumn?**

Comment: You can't use the same DataTemplate for data objects with different properties. However, if you have declared multiple DataTemplates for the same type (or types with identical property names), you could move that to Window.Resources, without setting `x:Key`, but instead only set its `DataType` property. Such a DataTemplate resource would be automatically selected whenever content of the appropriate type should be displayed.